# JavaScript- get sum of values inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, sum

I'm trying to sum all the variables, 
as many times as they appear in the loop, 
that is- for example if hitpoints appears
 3 times(as in my code) sum -12 + -12 + -12; 
And then at the end I need a final result - a
 sum of all of the variable values as many
 times as they appear.

```
    function calculate(number) {

    var hitpoints = -12;
    var points1 = 1;
    var points3 = 5;
    var points5 = 10;
    var pointsx = 15;

    for (var i =1; i <= number; i++) {

      if ( i%10 ===0) {
        console.log( i + "-" + hitpoints);
      } else if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i% 5 ===0)) {
        console.log( i + "-" + pointsx);
      } else if (i %3 ===0) {
        console.log ( i + "-" + points3);
      } else if (i%5 ===0) {
        console.log( i + "-" + points5);
      } else {
        console.log( i + "-" + points1);
      }
    }
  }

  calculate(30);
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Your code is working fine ? what is the expected output?

Comment: Do you want the sum of the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the sum of the points.
Declare a variable sum and keep incrementing

```js
function calculate(number) {
  var hitpoints = -12;
  var points1 = 1;
  var points3 = 5;
  var points5 = 10;
  var pointsx = 15;
  var sum=0;
  for (var i =1; i <= number; i++) {
    if ( i%10 ===0) {
      sum += hitpoints;
    } else if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i% 5 ===0)) {
      sum += pointsx;
    } else if (i %3 ===0) {
      sum += points3;
    } else if(i%5 ===0) {
      sum += points5;
    } else {
      sum += points1; 
    }
  }
  console.log(sum)
} 
calculate(30);
```